# Java(android) configuration files(scripts)

Tags: java, android, configuration-files

I have to be able to update my android application behavior using configuration files. The idea is as follows:

- There is a configuration file(any kind of semantic is allowed here)
  available on server.
- Android application downloads a configuration file if it is more up to date
  then the local one.
- Configuration file should handle setting constant values and expressions.

What kind of expressions? For example

```
if number_of_rows_in_database > 2:
some_flag = true
```

Are there any libraries/classes/functions available on Android, which makes that easier?

Comment: Well for saving constant values you should use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Ok and constants I can send as an xml <foo>bar</foo>. But what to do with expressions?

Comment: I cannot hard code them cause they will vary in time.